# How to add a string to a string read in a text file in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary text file and I want to add to every word a string like `"http://" + word + ".com"`
I tried this:

```
      f = open('esp.txt', 'r')
      urls = open('urls.txt', 'w')
      while True:
          nline = 1
          contentCOM = 'http://www.' + f.readlines(nline) + '.com'
          contentCOM.write(urls)
          nline = nline + 1
```

But it gives me the following error: `TypeError: Must be str, not list`

Comment: Bummer. When you researched that error and determined what line it came from, what did you find?

Comment: Your question is not complete. What is the content of the file `exp.txt`? (You could show just a few lines.) What is the full traceback for the error? Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, did you look at the line number given in the traceback? Do you understand just what is returned by `f.readlines()`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `urls.write(contentCOM)` instead? btw, how does your program end?

Comment: @EJ2015 It should be obvious: It ends as soon as writing the zillionth copy of `'http://www..com'` to the file results in an error from running out of disk space. And, because it doesn't bother to flush or close the file, the last few writes probably get thrown away, meaning you still have just enough disk space for the shell to start spewing warnings at you about being out of space for temporary files instead of crashing. This seems like a great design by the OP. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your "words" are on one line after another in the esp.txt, then you can iterate like this:

```
f = open('esp.txt', 'r')
urls = open('urls.txt', 'w')
for lines in f:
    urls.write('http://www.' + lines + '.com' + '\n')

f.close()
urls.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `readlines()` vs the singular `readline()`

https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

The hint is that if you look at the error and the line number you'd notice you're getting a list instead of a string here:

```
contentCOM = 'http://www.' + f.readlines(nline) + '.com'
```

It would have been good to check the Python Documentation and look at the output of `readlines()` and see what the output is. Then you would have put together that the list output is your error and would have looked for a new function.